# C++ - What can be done with internal compiler errors?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, internal

I encountered something interesting and annoying while programming a matrix class: internal compiler error. I was willing to invoke a sister constructor in the class called `Matrix4<T>::Matrix4(Matrix4<T>&&)`. This is the piece of code that generates this error:

```
template<typename T>
Matrix4(Matrix4&& matrix_) = default;

template<typename T>
Matrix4<T>::Matrix4(T (&&matrix_)[4][4]):
    Matrix4({
        .data = {
            {matrix_[0][0], matrix_[0][1], matrix_[0][2], matrix_[0][3]},
            {matrix_[1][0], matrix_[1][1], matrix_[1][2], matrix_[1][3]},
            {matrix_[2][0], matrix_[2][1], matrix_[2][2], matrix_[2][3]},
            {matrix_[3][0], matrix_[3][1], matrix_[3][2], matrix_[3][3]}
        }
    })
{

}
```

And, this is the internal compiler error (*compiler is GCC and IDE is Code::Blocks*):

> internal compiler error: in process_init_constructor_array, at
>   cp/typeck2.c:1080

Supposedly the compiler cannot successfully parse my code. I'm pretty sure the syntax is alright, though. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: You can file a bug report.

Comment: @jrok: I'm very new to this. How can I do that?

Comment: [http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/). As for any bug report, make sure it isn't already reported or fixed and that your code is indeed correct.

Comment: @jrok: Well, is the code correct? Can you tell? :/

Comment: It's correct AFAICT. What version is this? Try online at coliru.stackedcrooked.com or ideone with recent versions.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the code is correct or not - ICEs are still a compiler bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try compiling it with a different compiler. It's possible that there is a very subtle error with your code, and another compiler might be able to tell you more. I recommend trying out [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), as it has widely been touted for having [better error messages](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html), though the most recent versions of GCC are seeking to change this notion.

If it fails on both compilers without a real error message in sight, then you have some of the finest test-code for this bug at your disposal and submitting a bug report about it would be much appreciated by the compiler community.

Comment: Reported about this bug on GCC Bugzilla. If you are interested, you can find this specific bug here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57769

Comment: Did you try it in Clang though? EDIT: just read the bug report, looks like it was a version specific error in GCC.